# Javascript chained function call from dot notation string

Tags: javascript

I am using the [Faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) library which allows to generate dummy data for many types like name, addresses etc.
The library is used like this:

```
var faker = require('faker');
var random = faker.random.number();
```

I need to be able to call methods dynamically on faker instance from a string representing the property path.

**Example:**

Having a string variable with value "name.lastName", I need to be able to call faker like:

```
faker.name.lastName()
```

I am able to do call faker like this using hardcoded values but I am having trouble to use a variable instead:

```
Faker['random']['number']()
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you try to use the variable?